# Asp.Net MVC change views location for DisplayModeProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, razor

I develop massive web application with a lot of views. It is messy to keep desktop/mobile views in same folder. Is it possible to group mobile views (name.Mobile.cshtml) into explicit subfolder and say to DisplayModeProvider to find views there?
For example,

`Views/Home/Index.Mobile.cshtml` moves to `Views/Home/Mobile/Index.Mobile.cshtml`
`Views/People/List.Mobile.cshtml` moves to `Views/People/Mobile/List.Mobile.cshtml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, i found some ways to resolve this problem.

1. I can implement custom RazorViewEngine(WebFormViewEngine) and specify my own `ViewLocationFormats` collection.
2. I can use Areas to achieve this behaviour.
3. I can implement custom DefaultDisplayMode and override `TransformPath()` method to change views location.

I think third way is more easy and simple way. Here is the code:

First i create custom DisplayMode and inherit it from DefaultDisplayMode:

```
public class NewDisplayMode : DefaultDisplayMode
{
    public NewDisplayMode()
        : base("Mobile") //any folder name you like, or you can pass it through parameter
    {

    }

    public NewDisplayMode(string folderName)
        : base(folderName) //any folder name you like, or you can pass it through parameter
    {

    }

    protected override string TransformPath(string virtualPath, string suffix)
    {
        string view = Path.GetFileName(virtualPath);
        string pathToView = Path.GetDirectoryName(virtualPath);
        virtualPath = (pathToView + "\\" + suffix + "\\" + view).Replace("\\", "/");

        return virtualPath;
    }
}
```

In the code above i override `TransformPath()` method and transform `virtualPath` string to change location to views.

Next all i need is to add this mode to modes collection:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.RemoveAt(0);
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new NewDisplayMode()
        {
            ContextCondition = context => context.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice
            //ContextCondition = context => context.Request.Url.Host == "www.m.mysite.com"
        });
        //other code
    }
```

Therefore, i do not need to rename my view files, i use same name for mobile and desktop views. Finally, my folders structure looks like so:

[image]

Comment: Great post, thanks. However, using your example code above my view engine is still looking for /Views/Home/Mobile/Index.mobile.cshtml instead of /Views/Home/Mobile/Index.cshtml - do you know what might be wrong?